# Unable to Install Ubuntu on hcl laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my HCL lpatop that has got the following properties

**intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU
T5250 @ 1.50GHz
233MHz, 0.99 GB of RAM**

I have tried **ubuntu 12** and **ubuntu 10** with  dual booting **Microsoft Windows XP
Professional 
version 2002
Service Pack 2**

But whenever i try to install, it boots from the city and shows the **Ubuntu logo**.

It keeps showing the ubuntu logo for a long time and then my laptop gets freeze, it shows blank screen..

I have tried this for several times with different versions but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

There is far more to a laptop than just the CPU and RAM, so when checking the HCL verify that the make and model of the laptop are on there. Please also verify the MD5SUM of the ISO that you downloaded and burned to the CD. I've seen similar issues with bad burns (or bad ISO downloads). You can get a list of the correct MD5SUMs for 12.04 from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/MD5SUMS

Comment: thanks for your reply, i already have checked the md5sum it matches. And the other things about my laptop you are talking about are : HCL INFINITI  POWERLITE 9100 PL with Intel Centrino Duo Mobile Technology, Intel GM965 Chipset,PCMCIA Card Slot,